# c# Wait did not seem to reacquire lock

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am not sure why this piece of code is not safe.  I have a test case to prove it is not safe.

```
        List<T> _l = new List<T>();
        public void Add(T t)
        {
            lock (_l)
            {
                _l.Add(t);
                Monitor.PulseAll(_l);
            }
        }
        public T[] RemoveToArray(TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            lock (_l)
            {
                if (_l.Count == 0)
                {
                    bool timedout = !Monitor.Wait(_l, timeout);

                    // no lock 
                    if (timedout)
                    {
                        return new T[0];
                    }
                }
                // with lock
                T[] items = _l.ToArray();
                _l.Clear();
                return items;
            }
        }
```

The function is supposed to wait for some amount of time (after which times out) for new items to arrive.  When times up, returns an empty array, otherwise drains all the elements in the internal list to an array.  In the test code, I created two Task, one to add, another to remove.

```
        times = 3;
        Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
        tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            firstRemoveItems = _l.RemoveToArray(_infinite);
            Util.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)).Wait();
            secondRemoveItems = _l.RemoveToArray(_infinite);
        });
        tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            _l.Add(new object());
            Util.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5)).Wait();
            for (int i = 1; i < times; i++)                
                _l.Add(new object());
        });
```

Three items have been added, however, the total number of items had been 2, 3, 4.  I am not quite sure what the issue is.  I assume the lock is reacquired after Wait times out?

Comment: Where you have 2,3,4? You remove items two times!

Comment: Is there a reason you are working with these low level collections and not using an abstraction like something from the [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace?

Comment: Yes, Monitor.Wait does not return (either timeout or not) until the lock is re-acquired.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I can, for this question, I want to understand what's wrong.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes, there're 2 RemoveToArray calls.  The total number of items drained should never exceed the numbers added.  So 4 is the big issue.

Comment: I have tested code with and without optimization. I never reached 4, in most cases i get 1,2 sometimes 1,1 which is normal.